# How?: Timestamp on Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to this but managed to drum up a timestamp on Google Sheets a little while ago by looking at a couple things online.

I'm really trying to get this to work across multiple sheets but am struggling, please may someone let me know where I've gone wrong. I've tried to put it in an array as suggested in other posts but instead of at least one sheet working, nothing works.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
 function onEdit(event) {

 var sheetName = 'RAIL'; //Selecting the sheet - need to add 'CIVILS' & 'SYSTEMS' sheets but when put in array ['RAIL', 'CIVILS', 'SYSTEMS']; nothing returns
     watchCol = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11], //Watches Columns for edits 
     stampCol = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], //Inserts the timestamp under "Last Updated" in sheet after edits
     ind = watchCol.indexOf(event.range.columnStart);
 if (event.source.getActiveSheet()
     .getName() !== sheetName ||  ind == -1 || event.range.rowStart < 2) return;
event.source.getActiveSheet()
         .getRange(event.range.rowStart, stampCol[ind])
         .setValue(event.value ? new Date() : null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an `if` statement:

```
var sheetnames = ['RAIL', 'CIVILS', 'SYSTEMS'];

if(sheetNames.indexOf(event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()) !== -1){

  if(event.range.columnStart > 0 && event.range.columnStart < 12){

    //edit has occurred on watched sheet, in watched column

  }
}
```